# python list have `-` formatting, and cannot using `-` as variables

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

cannot using `-` as variable but my list have `-` formatting, so i cannot change my list items, so how can I still keep `-` in list and saved all items ?

**looking** for **dynamic variable** for each `for loop` to **save** **difference** data on `each loop`

**Python code**

```
list = ['list-0','list-1','list-2']

for x in list:
    print(x)
    globals()[x] = 'a'+x

print(list-0)
print(list-1)
print(list-2)
```

**TypeError**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

**Work fine for following code**

```
list = ['list0','list1','list2']

for x in list:
    print(x)
    globals()[x] = 'a'+x

print(list0)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

**Result of work fine code**

```
alist0
alist1
alist2
```

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of trying to define variables.

Comment: Variable names can only contain letters, numbers, and underscore. `list-0` means to subtract `0` from the value of `list`.

Comment: dear, can i add string after to solve this problem ?

Comment: __Don’t__ do the `globals()[x]=‘a’+x` thing, there’s no need for that; what are you really trying to do?

Comment: dear, i want **dynamic variable** for each `for loop` to save difference data on each `loop`

Comment: @Mary Use a `dict` to save all the values.  There is no need to try to place these in the global namespace.  It's basically what you're doing with `globals()` anyway.  But instead of accessing them with `globals()[name]`, you can just do `mydict[name]` which makes much more sense.

Comment: dear, @TomKarzes any example for my references ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for your requirements, that way you can have their value dynamic as well as you can maintain the key name with the hyphen
`-`. This might help you:

```
list = ['list-0', 'list-1', 'list-2']
mapping = {}
for l in list:
    mapping[l] = 'a'+l

print(mapping['list-0'])
print(mapping['list-1'])
print(mapping['list-2'])

for l in list:
    mapping[l] = 'b'+l

print(mapping['list-0'])
print(mapping['list-1'])
print(mapping['list-2'])
```

Results:

```
alist-0
alist-1
alist-2
blist-0
blist-1
blist-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `dict` to hold the values.  For example:

```
list = ['list-0','list-1','list-2']
mydict = {}

for x in list:
    print(x)
    mydict[x] = 'a'+x

print(mydict['list-0'])
print(mydict['list-1'])
print(mydict['list-2'])
```